# Heroku cannot find Playwright files

Tags: node.js, docker, heroku, deployment, playwright

My TypeScript NodeJS (>=12.0.0) app uses [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) (^1.4.2). It runs well locally. But, it fails on Heroku:

```
browserType.launch: Failed to launch chromium because executable doesn't exist at /app/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-799411/chrome-linux/chrome

Try re-installing playwright with "npm install playwright"

Note: use DEBUG=pw:api environment variable and rerun to capture Playwright logs.

at BrowserType._wrapApiCall (/app/node_modules/playwright/lib/client/channelOwner.js:78:15)

at BrowserType.launch (/app/node_modules/playwright/lib/client/browserType.js:49:21)

at Object.exports.browserTest (/app/utils.js:34:57)

at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:13:9)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1076:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:32)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:782:14)

at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
```

So, I SSHed into the Heroku dyno and ran `npm install playwright`. Got the same error.

Then I thought, how about building it into a Docker image (node:latest) and then deploying it to Heroku? Surely that won't fail. It did. Same error. This image ran perfectly locally.

Following solutions online, I also tried installing several Heroku buildpacks, and using the [Chromium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/playwright-chromium) and [Firefox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/playwright-firefox) Playwright flavours specifically. I then tried a thousand and one other things I've forgotten (edit: including [mxschmitt heroku-playwright-example](https://github.com/mxschmitt/heroku-playwright-example)).

Anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: Would this help? https://github.com/mxschmitt/heroku-playwright-example

Comment: Thanks, @altarjun, but I've already tried that.

Comment: Hi, author of the Playwright Heroku buildpack here, are you using the buildpack as the first one in your buildpack list? order is important there otherwise the browsers won't get installed and get found correctly. https://github.com/mxschmitt/heroku-playwright-buildpack

Comment: @MaxSchmitt I thought I tried it already but I retried it today and it worked. Maybe I did something wrong before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

alterjun and MaxSchmitt point to [github.com/mxschmitt/heroku-playwright-buildpack](https://github.com/mxschmitt/heroku-playwright-buildpack), and it says the buildpacks are important. I tried it previously but must have done something wrong but now it's working.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work with new versions of playwright.